# java.reflection: How can I do method.invoke(clazz, varargs) with dynamic number of args?

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I want to do method calls using reflection via method.invoke(clazz, varargs) with varying number of arguments and realize this way the call of different methods with one call only and not via explicit, hard coded number of arguments. In the moment I do the following:

```
... 
determine method arguments via reflection
...
if (numberOfArguments == 0) {
    method.invoke(clazzInstance, null);
} else if (numberOfArguments == 1) {
    method.invoke(clazzInstance, arg0);
} else if (numberOfArguments == 2) {
    method.invoke(clazzInstance, arg0, arg1);
} ... etc
```

is there a way to do this more elegantly without the need for explicitly checking for the number of arguments?

Comment: Dump your arguments into an array of the appropriate size and call `method.invoke(clazzInstance, myArray)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

varargs are passed as an array, so you must create this array like in:

```
var args = Arrays.asList(arg1, ...).toArray()
```

or

```
var args = List.of(arg1, ...).toArray()
```

or even create a method, eventually the one you are already writing, receiving the varargs

```
void method(Object... args) {
    ...
```

All the above options having the method invoked like

```
method.invoke(instance, args);
```

<sup>it all depends on the whole context</sup>

Varargs are (almost) treated as arrays, that is, `type... args` is the same as `type[] args` inside the method, the compiler just convert the arguments to an array when calling such a method.

Comment: why did you create a list first and then convert it to an array?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko no, the first two are commands to create a `List<Object>`  and then an `Object[]` of that  (method `toArray` from `List`); on the 3rd code, the compiler is creating the array. There is also an option to pass an (per-allocated) array to `toArray` which is then eventually used, but this is mostly used to *force* a given return type for the array (instead of `Object[]`)

Answer (score 3):

Collect `arg0`, `arg1`, `argsN` into an `Object[]` array, truncate the size to `numberOfArguments` and pass it:

```
Object[] args = {arg0, arg1, ..., argsN};
method.invoke(clazzInstance, Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, numberOfArguments));
```

Answer (score 0):

if the method that you are invoking accept variable number of args of the same type, like

```
method(type...arg)
```

you can just use an array as a parameter

```
method.invoke(clazzInstance, arg[])
```

If the arguments are of different type I don't advise you to do a method like method(Object[]...obj) because you don't put any restriction on the types that the method have to work with, and this can lead to some error devolping the code